# Node js integrate windows authentication AD

Tags: node.js, active-directory, windows-authentication

I've been reading for the last hour but it's still not clear for me how to automatically authenticate the current windows user in my node js application.

On my office PC, I'm already authenticated with my AD user when I access our company portal in Chrome (as it was added as a trusted sites). So the main question for me is what do I have to do to automatically detect/authenticate the user in my nodejs app if I add my site to the trusted sites? I'm pretty sure the browser must do half of the job as it probably sends some kind of data (hash) in the request, based on which the application must authenticate the user. I suspect this is the "www-authenticate: negotiate" header as I noticed this sends a hash in the request when I access the portal.

So far, the only tracks I'm still investigating are:
https://gist.github.com/charlesdaniel/1686663

But it's still not very clear for me how this automatic authentication works and what are the leads I should follow next. The entire process is still unclear to me

I appreciate any advices on this or at least a mid-level explanation on what happens behind the scenes when I access a page in Chrome and it automatically authenticates me. Thanks

Comment: You should start here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi About [SSPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380493(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: any progress ? i also need same kind of feature